# Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKe

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-7-x64

I have a 3rd party DLL which I have integrated to my application. But when I try to call this DLL im getting the following error.

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed

So I tried so many things ad ended up with no success.

Tried this

```
  <system.web>
    <trust level="Full"  />
  </system.web>
```

and try adding group policy using gpedit.

Additionally after enabling `ClickOnce` option in project properties I can run everything smoothly with VS2010, but if I open the exe file in bin folder I'm getting this error.

I'm using .NET 4.0 with WIN 7 X64

Finally found something fishy. I'm using POS for .Net. In order to work POS for .net I need to include these lines in config file

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
```

But after inserting this, the above DLL starts giving the security exception.